# SwiftUI onTapGesture on a text navigate to another screen

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, hstack

I have a `Text` view. Once this `Text` is pressed I need to navigate to another view of my application. I tried with the `NavigationView` and `NavigationLink` but I'm not able to perform the navigation.

```
HStack(alignment: .bottom, spacing: 0) {
  Text("Already member? ")
    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                
  Text("Login now")
    .foregroundColor(.blue)
    .underline()
    .onTapGesture {
      // TODO: Navigate to LoginView()
    }
}
.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
.padding(.top, 40)
```

This is my tappable `Text`. I don't know if the problem with the `NavigationView` depends on the multiple text that I have in my `hstack`.

[image: What I need]

Comment: Use `$isActive` from `NavigationLink`.

Comment: The problem is that I need just a classic navigation without back button and also the navigation title. From the login view I need to go to the registration view and from the registration view I need to go to the login view.

Comment: `NavigationView {
///HStack...
NavigationLink(destination: LoginView().navigationBarHidden(true), isActive: $isActive) {EmptyView()}
}`
Set isActive==true on tap of LoginNow text.

Comment: Ok it works. There is a way to have a transition right to left in the case of going to the LoginView and left to right if I want come back?